# Free Alternatives to "Titanium Backup Pro"

Tags: titanium-backup

I have recently rooted my Samsung Galaxy Y phone and installed the Titanium Backup (free version). Anyhow, I am not satisfied with it as many of the features are unavailable and I am asked to get the paid version.

My Question is: Are there any free alternatives to the services offered in Titanium Backup Pro?

I am in particular looking for the **"Convert to user app"** and **"Enable 'multiple profiles' for this app"** features.

Comment: Email them and say you're tight on budget. They'll give you a legal copy.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Really? Never heard of anything like that.

Comment: Try.. See if you are lucky or not...

Comment: There is no real alternative to TB as to my knowledge -- and I would wonder if I had missed it. I'm using TB now for about 2 years (and yes, I got a legal key from Joel in return for a short TB manual I wrote, which he then used on his website -- that time there was none available, so this was a typical win-win situation). I would have paid for it even, but that time Swiss people could not sell their apps on the market... TB is one of the few apps for ~5 EUR up I say is worth every cent.

Comment: @Izzy I know that it's totally worth it.

Comment: And honestly, compared to what people pay for Windows software, prices for apps are peanuts (mostly; there are only very few more expensive than 5 bucks). <- Not intended to blame -- just a decent hint :D And now, I'm not running Windows (I only look through them) xD

Comment: @Izzy Even the Nokia Ovi Store has apps lot more expensive than android apps. Also, most of Nokia's apps do not work without internet connection - and use internet connection only and only to display adds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not aware of a full-blown replacement for Titanium Backup, but there are solutions for the specific functions you're after:

Recent versions of [Link2SD](http://www.link2sd.info/) can convert user apps to system apps and vice versa ([available on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD)).

[SwitchMe](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=21843503) offers a solution for switching among multiple user profiles ([available on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.switchme)). The free version is limited to two profiles and "no security features".

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any **free** alternatives to the services offered in Titanium Backup Pro?

In the context of software, the word "free" is ambiguous. Do you mean [*libre*, or *gratis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre), or both?

The following software packages ostensibly provide functionality that may make them adequate replacements for Titanium Backup Pro, depending on your use case. They are all *free software*. That is, they provide the [four freedoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Free_software&oldid=730117990#Definition_and_the_Four_Freedoms).

- [Amaze](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=backup&fdid=com.amaze.filemanager) file manager;
- [oandbackup](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=dk.jens.backup);
- [Team Win Recovery Project (TWRP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TWRP).

Comment: Noble response. But who are we kidding? We all know the op meant gratis, especially with the mention of "... I am asked to get the paid version." :-\

Comment: Fortunately for the OP, those apps are also gratis :)

Comment: oandbackup is great and free as libre/freedom.